# iwlwifi driver wont load

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, asus, intel

Just installed ubuntu 22.04 on a computer with windows 11 that was working just fine, but it does seem that the drivers for my wifi adapter are failing to load.

Model Asus UM325UA

Kernel version 6.2.0-34-generic

```
 sudo dmesg | grep iw
[    3.753523] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.835306] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I tried loading the drivers from the intel page but the error persists

```
Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265       4.6+        iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz
sudo cp ./iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Some logs

```
pci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:9010]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

lspci
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

and

```
sudo  lshw -C network

 *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 78
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fcf00000-fcf01fff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 9
   bus info: usb@2:1
   logical name: enx0c3796697b2b
   serial: 0c:37:96:69:7b:2b
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8156b-2 v1 04/15/21 ip=192.168.0.105 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

fast boot and secure boot disabled
reinstalled modules extra

```
sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-34-generic
```

the error code persists

Answer (score 0):

Update: Today I woke up and it just fine with good speeds

```
 sudo dmesg | grep iw
[    3.558070] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.569653] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.744330] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[    3.806230] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 38:fc:98:f2:fb:98, OTP minor version: 0x0
[    3.882185] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.889677] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0


sudo  lshw -C network
 *-network                 
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
      logical name: wlp1s0
      version: 78
      serial: 38:fc:98:f2:fb:98
      width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-34-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8265-36.ucode ip=192.168.0.198 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:86 memory:fcf00000-fcf01fff
```

I had rebooted multiple times last night I dont know what happend but it just works!
[Speed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe5IB.png)